# Excel - how to extract certain rows from a column into a concise table

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have these two columns in Excel.  Group Numbers in col A and Value (some relevant numeric data) in next column B.

I need to extract only the rows for Group 1 into a separate columns or a table as shown in the picture.
I want to avoid Filters & Copy-Paste because the values may change over time.

I am using INDEX function with a helper column to achieve this. However is there a better solution without the Helper Column with a direct working formula? I am using Excel 2013
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO1H9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the data is already  organized into a specific pattern of groups:  *(1,2,3,1,2,3,...)* Given this pattern, in **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$16,1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*3),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

If, however, the data was not organized by alternating groups, then an *array formula* would be needed.